# Maven multi module project release with different versions

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

If I have a multi module project where modules have different versions, what happens during a release when only one of the modules has changed and has a new version? Does only that module/jar gets deployed and released? How many tags will be created? What happens to the other modules/tags?

Comment: If you have multi module build where the modules have different versions this sounds like you shouldn't use a multi module build.